# Crystal Reports Report Error

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I am un-sure what is going on here, when I generate the report the boxed section is bringing up all of the values for all of the results. how do I make it so these are separate.

This image is showing the report

[image]

this image is showing the table links

[image]

this image is showing the code in the sub report.

[image]

If you require any other information, please just ask.

Many thanks,

Daniel

Comment: I believe the sub-report is necessary, normally I can just find the field name tool tips from the program we are using to create simple reports but in this instance there isn't a field for the information to be pulled from, it is from a table instead. I used this sub-report from another report that someone else created (which seemed to work there)

Answer (score 0):

So you want to restrict the values in the subreport to be the values in the main report?  You are probably looking for a feature called "Subreport Linking".   Try here:  http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/go/portal/prtroot/docs/library/uuid/d05ad954-f8a2-2e10-db9f-bb0f13a7cb1c?QuickLink=index&overridelayout=true&51887500358899